# Is it possible to use JavaScript inside handlebars.js template

Tags: javascript, paypal, handlebars.js

The description says it all.
How to put a JavaScript script inside handlebars template.

I want to make a dynamic Paypal button for my website.

> ```
>       <script type="text/x-mustache-template" id="product-item-thumbnail-template">
>       <h2>{{title}}</h2>
>       <p>{{message}}</p>
>       <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
>       <p><script src="resources/js-frameworks/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=myemail@GMAIL.COM"
>             data-button="buynow"
>             data-name="My product"
>             data-amount="1.00"></script></p>
> </script>
> ```

But this produces an error because of the  tag. it closes the template script and not the paypal script

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try breaking up the "/script" part:

```
<script ...><{{!}}/script>
```

That technique is similar to older hacks like

```
<script>document.write("<script>...<\/script>");</script>
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. handlebars really need to do something active about this problem. its quite embarrassing if you ask me

Comment: Sorry it actually doesn't work as well... did it work for you? i am still getting a syntax error

Comment: @Gleeb the handlebar hackers can't do anything about that problem. The standard mandates that the script element is over as soon as the first `</script` occurrence was found in the source code. Actually I did not test my solution, but I was quite sure that it would solve the problem. I updated a handlebars example to contain a script tag and it works for me (in Firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/xfWKF/12/

Comment: Sorry for the mess but there is actually an error in the paypal .js file. i don't get it. it works with the mini cart version

Comment: Where does the script actually go though? Where the ... is? Or where the ! is? Excuse me, I'm new to this.

Comment: @bluemunch, I did not understand you. Could you reword your question, please.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it! I was just wondering where to place the actual javascript. Between the end of each tag, as usual. I was just confused because of that extra notation.