# How to run <script src= > tag from javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having some difficulties implementing Paypal buttons with backbone.js

The problem is that the button is implemented in a script tag:

> ```
> <script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=YOUR_MERCHANT_ID"
> data-button="buynow"
> data-name="My product"
> data-amount="1.00"></script>
> ```

which i cant run from Handlebars.js because the `</script>` tag is closing the handlebars `<script>`

I cant use eval(), or i don't understand how i am supposed to do that with the .

So there you have it. i am kind of stuck. I am out of ideas on how to implement this button with backbone.js the last resort is to ask the server to produce html pages with the script in them and then load them to the page.

i am just refusing to believe that JavaScript has no way to take care of this.

Please help.

This question relates to another question i asked in this subject.

[Is it possible to use JavaScript inside handlebars.js template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369855/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-inside-handlebars-js-template)

Comment: Handlebarsjs is a LOGICLESS template engine. Its not ment to run JS or any logic at all, consider using a different template engine like [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/)

Comment: What if you replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`?

Comment: its a different question with different answers and i mentioned that other post because it is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create the [equivalent DOMElement in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) and append it to the DOM, eg:

```
// Start by creating an empty `<script />` tag element
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");

// You can now start adding attributes to the element:
scriptTag.setAttribute("data-button", "buynow");

// Set the src attribute, note it won't start loading yet.
scriptTag.src = "paypal-button.min.js?merchant=YOUR_MERCHANT_ID";

// In order for it to become part of the page, you need to attach it
// to the DOM, to keep things clean, we will append it to the page's
// <head /> tag.
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```